# assignment to 'int' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I am trying to make a linked list stack, and I followed a tutorial online, however I get this warning, and the author does not.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct stack {
    int data;  
    struct stack *next;

} stack;

stack *top;


void Initialize(stack *s){
    s=malloc(sizeof(stack));
    s->data=NULL;
    s->next=NULL;
    top=s;

    
    return;
}
```

During debugging I get a segmentation fault, if I don't use `malloc` in the initialize function.
MINGW-W64 compiler.

Comment: You seem to miss a bit of code. This doesn't even have a main, so we can't run this code to see your problem.

Comment: `NULL` is often (but not always) defined as `#define NULL ((void *)0)`, which would lead to the warning in the assignment `s->data = NULL;` since `s->data` has type `int`. Perhaps you should use `s->data = 0;` instead. Also, you do not show how function `Initialize` is called, but the argument corresponding to parameter `s` is ignored by the function.

Comment: Either there is something wrong in function `Initialize` or the function argument `stack *s` is useless and should be replaced with a local variable. The value `s` passed to the function is immediately overwritten with the result of `malloc`. The caller of `Initialize` will not get the modified value as the pointer `s` is passed by value. 2nd problem: You should check the return value of `malloc`. If it returns a `NULL` pointer, the following accesses to `s->data` and `s->next` are invalid.

Comment: The function argument is useless, since you assign the pointer to the global `stack *top;`

Comment: @Sumsar It is evident that the author of the tutorial is a low-qualified programmer.:)

Comment: Most online tutorials are unfortunately trash, written by naive students rather than experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is due to the fact the the `NULL` macro is defined (by most modern compilers) as `((void *)0)`, as it is *intended* to be used only for pointers.  Assigning this value to the `data` member of your structure causes the warning.

To remove this warning, use `s->data=0;` in place of `s->data=NULL;`. The author of the tutorial is *either* using an older compiler *or* has disabled this particular warning.

Also, the pointer (`s`) passed to your `Initialize` function will be a **copy** of whatever variable you use as an argument when you call that function and, as such, its value is *not* updated in the calling code. You haven't specified how you intend to use that function, but here is a (perhaps) better implementation:

```c
stack* Initialize(void) { // Don't need an argument - just return the 'answer'
    stack* made = malloc(sizeof(stack));
    if (made) { // Don't attempt the initialization if "malloc" failed!
        made->data = 0;
        made->next = NULL;
    }
    return made;
}
```

And then, when you call that function, you can assign its returned value to your 'global' `top` pointer:

```c
//...
top = Initialize();
// You should check that 'top' is not NULL before continuing!
```

Comment: You could use something like: `stack *test = Initialize ();` and then add an `assert(test != NULL)` before your other checks.

Answer (score 0):

In C the macro NULL is defined like

```
( void * )0
```

that is the type of the expression is a null pointer of the type `void *`.

Thus in this statement

```
s->data=NULL;
```

a pointer is assigned to an object of the type `int` and the compiler issues a message saying that you are doing something wrong.

The function Initialize as it is written does not make a sense. Apart of all for example this statement

```
s=malloc(sizeof(stack));
```

does not change the original pointer `top` used as the function argument.

In fact the function is redundant.

Nevertheless if to write such a function then it can look either like

```
stack * Initialize( void )
{
    return NULL;
}
```

and called like

```
stack *top = Initialize();
```

or like

```
void Initialize( stack **top )
{
    *top = NULL;
}
```

Or for a new created node it can be declared and defined like

```
void Initialize( stack *s, int data, stack *next )
{
    s->data = data;
    s->next = next;
}
```